# Get additional Active directory attributes from Principal instead of DirectorySearcher's SearchResult

Tags: c#, active-directory, userprincipal

I would like to get some additional AD attributes from the AD user. I want to use `PrincipalSearcher` instead of `DirectorySearcher`.

What I did was get the underlyingSearcher of the PrincipalSearcher and called FindOne() method. I don't like to use GetUnderlyingSearcher from PrincipalSearcher, but apparently it works.

The code works, but I'm wondering if there is a way to read additional properties/Ad attributes from `Principal`

```
Principal match = principalSearcher.FindOne();
```

Additionally could below code have some problems because we are using the underlyingSearcher (DirectorySearcher) methods.

I find `PrincipalSearcher` more higher level and also if I would use DirectorySearcher the ldapPath must be defined `e.g. var ldapPath = "DC=corp,DC=ad,DC=example,DC=com";` It's just less lines of code.

```
public AdSimpleObject GetUser(string userName, string domainName)
{
  PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName);

  UserPrincipal userPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(principalContext);
  userPrincipal.SamAccountName = userName; // where condition

  using (PrincipalSearcher principalSearcher = new PrincipalSearcher(userPrincipal))
  {
    using (DirectorySearcher ds = (DirectorySearcher)principalSearcher.GetUnderlyingSearcher())
    {
      // get only properties we need, therefore search performance is increased
      ds.PropertiesToLoad.Clear();
      ds.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(new string[]
      {
        "sAMAccountType", 
        "sAMAccountName", 
        "userPrincipalName", 
        "msDS-PrincipalName"
      });

      SearchResult match = ds.FindOne();

      if (match != null)
      {
          AdSimpleObject ado = this.CreateAdSimpleObject(match);
          return ado;
      }  
      return null;
    }
  }
}

public class AdSimpleObject
{
  public string AdsPath { get; set; }
  public int SamAccountType { get; set; }
  public string SamAccountName { get; set; }
  public string MsDsPrincipalName { get; set; }
  public string UserPrincipalName { get; set; }
}

private AdSimpleObject CreateAdSimpleObject(SearchResult searchItem)
{
  ResultPropertyCollection props = searchItem.Properties;

  string adsPath = props["adspath"]?.OfType<string>().ToList().FirstOrDefault() ?? string.Empty;
  int samAccountType = props["sAMAccountType"]?.OfType<int>().ToList().FirstOrDefault() ?? 0;
  string samAccountName = props["sAMAccountName"]?.OfType<string>().ToList().FirstOrDefault() ?? string.Empty;
  string userPrincipalName = props["userPrincipalName"]?.OfType<string>().ToList().FirstOrDefault() ?? string.Empty;
  string msDsPrincipalName = props["msDS-PrincipalName"]?.OfType<string>().ToList().FirstOrDefault() ?? string.Empty;

  return new AdSimpleObject
  {
      AdsPath = adsPath,
      SamAccountType = samAccountType,
      SamAccountName = samAccountName,
      UserPrincipalName = userPrincipalName,
      MsDsPrincipalName = msDsPrincipalName
  };
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm wondering if there is a way to read additional properties/Ad attributes from `Principal`

You would use the [`DirectoryEntry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directoryentry?view=netframework-4.8) object returned from [`Principal.GetUnderlyingObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principal.getunderlyingobject?view=netframework-4.8):

```
Principal match = principalSearcher.FindOne();
var de = (DirectoryEntry) match.GetUnderlyingObject();
de.RefreshCache(new string[] {"someAttribute"});
var someAttribute = de.Properties["someAttribute"].Value;
```

Doing this will go back out to AD to get the attributes, instead of using the data that was retrieved in the search. The use of `RefreshCache` is to tell it to only get the attributes you are interested in. Otherwsie, if you use `DirectoryEntry.Properties` right away, it will go out to AD and get *all attributes that have a value*, which is unlikely what you need, and will just take extra time for no reason.

> Additionally could below code have some problems because we are using the underlyingSearcher (DirectorySearcher) methods.

Not at all. That code is no different than just making your own `DirectorySearcher` and using it. In fact, with the way you've written this code, there is no real point to using `UserPrincipal`/`PrincipalSearcher` at all. The only thing it's done for you is build the query string.

The whole [`AccountManagement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement?view=netframework-4.8) namespace is just a wrapper around `DirectoryEntry`/`DirectorySearcher`. It makes things easier for the programmer (in some cases, not all), but it does so at the cost of performance.

If you use `DirectoryEntry`/`DirectorySearcher` yourself directly, you have far more control over how much data is retrieved from AD, and how often network requests are made. Those translate into less time taken. If you're just searching for one account, then it won't make much of a difference. But if you're searching for large groups of users, or looping over a large list of users, it can make a huge difference.

I wrote an article about optimizing performance when talking to AD (specifically with `DirectoryEntry`/`DirectorySearcher`): [Active Directory: Better performance](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/12/15/better-performance-activedirectory.html)

Comment: I was under the impression that using PrincipalSearcher would avoid me from doing `ldapPath`, but it's hidden in the PrincipalContext that PrincipalSearcher use through UserPrincipal . Like you mentioned the query string is build for you. One provides domain in DirectoryEntry. Didn't know about `RefreshCache`, I saw it in other people's code, but didn't take the time to investigate it. Thank you very much. Specially for 'ould below code have some problems' -> not at all. I just wish AD API would be more easy or at least more documented with examples and such.

Comment: I must  also try what  happens if I run `principalSearcher.FindOne()` after `SearchResult match = ds.FindOne();`

Comment: It would just rerun the search. If you really want to dig into it, the source code for the .NET Core implementation (which should be much the same as the .NET Framework) is available [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/d3911035f2ba3eb5c44310342cc1d654e42aa316/src/System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement/src/System/DirectoryServices/AccountManagement). But it's quite difficult to follow the code through the various classes.

Comment: Thnx for the link to source code. I doubt I would have the time to investigate the code, but it gives me some more peace, because you can always look at how exactly does ad work. One more question, perhaps do you know what is the difference between `objectCategory=person` and `objectCategory=user`

Comment: I've been able to return a custom collection of over 3000 users via PrincipalSearcher in about 3 seconds so I wouldn't say it's all that slow.  I'll have to test this versus DirectorySearcher.  There were a couple of properties on DirectorySearcher performance that you missed that are very important. 1) Only load properties you need, otherwise you're doing basically a SELECT * query 2) Consider ReferralChasingOption.  Default is External which is slow.  If you're not looking across domains you don't need it.  Makes a difference.

Comment: I've also found just putting in the domain name (company.abc.com) in the path to be faster than using the IP of a server or host name.  Apparently if you just put domain name, the OS picks the best server to hit based on some algorithm.